# Proof by induction $4^n - 1 = k (2^n + 1)$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I'm stuck with proving the inductive step. Assume $4^n - 1 = k (2^n + 1)$, where $k$ is any integer.
$$4(4^n - 1) = 4k_1 (2^n + 1)$$
$$4^{n+1} - 4 = 2k_1 (2^{n+1} + 2)$$
$$4^{n+1} - 1 = 2k_1 (2^{n+1} + 2) + 3$$
What should I do to get $4^{n+1} = k_2 (2^{n+1} + 1)$?

Comment: Note:  $4^n-1=(2^n-1)(2^n+1)$

Comment: I don't think I could use that

Comment: If you can prove that $2k_1+3=k_2(2^{n+1}+1)$ then you're done, I don't see how you can do this without using $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ but perhaps it's possible.

Comment: @AcidResin Well...Why don't you try the easier way?  I just wondered.

Comment: I'm required to do induction

Comment: It might be necessary (as @J.W.Tanner indicates) to identify $k$ to make the induction work ...

Comment: Should I cancel $2^n+1$ from both sides?

Comment: Once you do that, you have the proof suggested by @J.W.Tanner, which doesn't use induction.

Comment: Interestingly, the same question has been asked before. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4139197/460967

Comment: That question doesn't require induction as proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a strictly inductive proof.

We have

$$4^n-1=k(2^n+1)\tag{1}$$

and wish to conclude that with some suitable integer $k'$ it follows that

$$4^{n+1}-1 = k'(2^{n+1}+1)\tag{2}$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $4$ gives

$$4^{n+1}-4=2k(2^{n+1}+2)=2k(2^{n+1}+1)+2k$$

or

$$4^{n+1}-1=2k(2^{n+1}+1)+2k+3$$

now letting $2k=k'-1$ this reads

$$\begin{align}4^{n+1}-1
& =(k'-1)(2^{n+1}+1)+(k'-1)+3\\
& =k'(2^{n+1}+1)-2^{n+1}-1+k'-1+3
\\
& =k'(2^{n+1}+1)+\left(k'-(2^{n+1}-1)\right)\\
& =k'(2^{n+1}+1)\end{align}\tag{3}$$

which gives $(2)$ because we can let the bracket in the second but last line of $(3)$ vanish setting

$$k'=2^{n+1}-1\tag{4}$$

This completes the inductive proof.

Comment: Wait. Where did $-2^{n+1}+k'+1$ go?

Comment: This expression becomes zero by defining $k'$ appropriately by $(4)$.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, it's better to do this directly.

If we had to use induction, one approach might be to observe that (EG by expanding both sides)

$$ (2^{n+1} + 1 ) ( 2\times (4^n - 1)  + 2^n + 1 ) = (4^{n+1} - 1 ) ( 2^n + 1 ).  $$

Hence

$$ 2 \times \frac{ 4^n -1  } { 2^n + 1 }  + 1 = \frac{ 4^{n+1 } - 1 } { 2^{n+1 } + 1}. $$

This completes the induction step.

---

Of course, this is just saying that $ 2 \times (2^n -1 ) + 1 = 2^ { n+1 }  - 1$.
Also, we're implicitly using $ 4^n - 1 = (2^n -1 ) ( 2^n + 1)$ in verification of the expansion.